# outputs parameters of cvCalibrateCamera

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm using OpenCV calibrateCamera function to extract intrinsic end extrinsic parameters of my camera. I have a big problem with the extrinsic one (rotation and translation) because the rotation matrix, that should be a 3x3 matrix, it's only a 3x1. Does someone know why I have this output or how can I use it? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you read the documentation again, you will understand why it is 3x1 matrix. Here is the [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a vector which is actually the [axis-angle representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle) of your rotation. You can convert that in a 3x3 rotation matrix using the Rodrigues formula:

[Rodrigues on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)

[Rodrigues using OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues)

Comment: How can the resulting rotation matrix be used to transform each calibration image into the world frame, and what should this result look like?